# propagate custom field value in data extension to tracking events

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I have a Data Extension with a custom unique ID as the primary key so that two recipients can have the same email address. Then, I use Email Send Definition to send the emails to those recipients defined in the DE.

My question is, when I want to track the Open Events, Click Events, etc., how can I tell which row of the Data Extension this event belongs to? In other words, is there a way for the Open Event to hold the custom unique ID for that row in the data extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "unique field" should also be your susbcriberkey. That way the system data views that track opens, clicks and other events would record them against this unique value

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But I was wondering if there is a way to propagate additional recipient metadata (other than the SubscriberKey) to the tracking events as well.

Comment: Have you looked at Send Logging? You can capture send specific data with this feature.

Comment: I did, so I tried to capture the additional metadata field (which is another unique key for each row) in a SendLog DE and that was fine. However if I have multiple recipients with the same SubscriberKey (i.e. email Address) and I try join my SendLog DE to Open system data view for example, joined on Job ID and SubscriberKey, I would get multiple OpenEvent to the same SubscriberKey and cannot tell which one belongs to the other metadata field.

Comment: Multiple recipients cannot have the same subscriberkey in marketing cloud. A subscriberkey represents a unique contact. That's where the flaw is.

Comment: So, in that case, I should be able to set a SubscriberKey to some unique id other than the email address, right? However, when I try to create a data extension with SendableSubscriberField.Name = "Subscriber Key", I get this error: The SendableSubscriberField cannot be SubscriberKey because the SUBSCRIBER_KEY business rule has not been turned on.

Comment: Then get support to activate it